# How to preset the username in Djangos login form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

After being dissatisfied with the existing solutions I wrote an OpenId provider for Django.

If now somebody wants to authenticate himself somewhere as *http://tejp.de/users/abc/* and needs to login for that, I want to display the login form with the username preset to "abc". The standard functions like `redirect_to_login` don't seem to provide any parameters for this and I also don't see how I could preset that value when redirecting to the login view in `django.contrib.auth.views.login` manually. Also there seems to be no easy way to get an additional parameter value through to the template, so that I could maybe insert the preset value there.

Is there a way to automatically fill in a username in the login form? If possible I'd like to use the normal login view for this, not copy&paste all the login code and edit in the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, django is all python, and the source is your friend.

Here's the original source for `redirect_to_login`.

```
def redirect_to_login(next, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    "Redirects the user to the login page, passing the given 'next' page"
    if not login_url:
        login_url = settings.LOGIN_URL 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?%s=%s' % (login_url, urlquote(redirect_field_name), urlquote(next)))
```

It looks like you could even just override login_url with a link to a URL that takes the appropriate parameters.  Something like

```
return redirect_to_login(login_url=reverse('my_login_view', [], {'username': username}))
```

You don't need a new form, you just need to prepopulate the existing login form.

Answer (score -1):

Some of ways to solve the above problem are:

1. Write your own authentication form and prefill the username before displaying.
2. Use javascript to strip a username from url and put it down in the form.